# Can I use .txt filenames "dynamically" as Keys for a python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, calculation

First of all, sorry for my bad englisch - please bear with me.

Secondly; can I create a dictionary so "dynamically", that I can use the "Endings" of the .txt Files I want to read/open with the script as keys for a dictionary?

The Background is; I've made alot of measurments, yet I forgot to put in a certain Variable in the .txt Files. Those .txt files though do contain sometimes over 5000 lines (Time measurments e.g.).

Yet I've actually only 13 different values I forgot. The .txt Files are all named after a certain plan, so the Ending _12 or _01 will be always the same value I miss for a calculation in the script.

The issue right now is, that I don't exactly know how connect the key to the file name properly and how to "convert" the Dictionary to a "proper" value. (Getting the TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'dict') - Although I think the later problem could be solved by creating a tuple?

Thank y'all in advance.

I tried first to create a simple dict and then use simple "J=I*A", ideally A would be a certain variable from the dictionary, depending on the Filename the I is from via Dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're obviously already opening the file(s) in your program, so you should be able to adapt the following to get the value you want from the file in question:

```
filename = "relative_or_abs_path_to_your_file_01.txt"

# Returns a list with extension ('txt') as element 1, and the rest of the filename as element 0
f = filename.rsplit('.', 1)

# Split on element 0 (the filename element) to get value after the underscore (element 1 of the returned list)
missing_value = f[0].rsplit('_', 1)[1]

missing_value = int(missing_value)  # Convert into an integer
print(missing_value)
```

Once you have the `missing_value` variable, you can obviously put it into a `dict`, or wherever you need it, to accommodate the rest of your code. (Or just use it directly as-is.)

Comment: You are most welcome. Please consider marking my answer as accepted, if you think it deserves it.  Thank you.

Comment: Ah, sorry I'm new here so I didn't realized I could do so - Just tried to give you an "upvote" but couldn't.

Comment: No problem at all; most people don't when they first join, so please don't worry. Many thanks for doing so now. The answer you mark as accepted cannot be upvoted by you as well (accepted answer = 15 points of reputation and an upvote is 10 points). Don't worry, you'll soon get used to it all. Welcome to Stack Overflow!